# is there any way to add a custom library to jre

Tags: java

there are some codes that I use very often in my programs and its kind of annoying to add it to my program every time I'm wondering if there is any way to solve this problem like adding

Comment: You could use maven

Comment: Can you be more detailed. What do you mean by "every time"? Every time you do *what*? Create a new project? A new class? You seem to be asking about some re-use of code, but it's unclear what *level* of re-use you talk about. Specific examples would go a long way towards understanding that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Java used to have the extension mechanism, but it was removed because the new module system, and because it was abused and caused all kinds of issue exactly because all the applications using the same JVM would use that library, even if an application didn't expect it, or required a different versions, etc. Or do you want to have some generic library that you can reuse in your different applications?